# Ansible shell module problem

Tags: ansible

i need to clear the contents of a file on remote hosts using shell module in ansible but unable to do so

```
---
 - hosts: ansi1
   become: yes
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
   - name: checking shell power
     shell:
        >/tmp/1.txt
     args:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

Error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/shell.yml': line 8, column 10, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

     shell:
        >/tmp/1.txt
         ^ here
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted a colon in front? (The 'true' operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jeff Schaller this helped to solve the issue,,

```
---
 - hosts: ansi2
   become: yes
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
   - name: checking shell power
     shell:
             '>/tmp/1.txt'
     args:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

Now what if i have multiple commands to run

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as below for multiple commands:

```
    - name: Copy var directory
      shell: |
        cmd1
        cmd2
        cmd3
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```

Comment: @Mohammed Ali if this works Can you please accept the answer